# Stabilization of one special matrix by a diagonal matrix, interpretation of Fisher's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the next $n\times n$ real square matrix
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ C & E \end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A$ is a positive definite matrix of dimensions $m\times m$, with $3 \leq m < n$. My objective is to make all the eigenvalues of $DP$ with positive real part, where $D = diag(d_1, \dots, d_n)$ and $d_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

The Fisher's Theorem published in the paper titled "*On the stabilization of matrices and the convergence of linear iterative processes*" states that

If $P$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix fulfilling the condition:

(A): $P$ has at least one sequence of non-zero principal minors $M_k$ of every order $k = 1,2, ...,n$, such that $M_{k-1}$ is one of the $k$ first principal minors of $M_k$; then there exists a real diagonal matrix $D = diag (d_i)$ such that the characteristic equation of $DP$ is stable.

In my case for $P$, the principal minors concerning $A$ ($M_1, \dots, M_m$)  are always non-zero (positive since $A$ is positive definite). Can I apply this theorem to my matrix $P$? I do not understand what is the required sequence of principal minors in the theorem (i.e. does the sequence include $M_n$ necessarily?), therefore I do not know whether I can apply the theorem.

Thanks in advance

### EDIT

Well, finally I have figured out how to construct such sequences. Unfortunately for my matrix $P$ I can not say anything for $M_{n+1}$, therefore I can not apply directly the theorem. One property of my matrix $P$ is that all the diagonal elements are positive, based on that, lets see if I can find some properties for $B, C$ and $E$.

Comment: If this is do-able, then it is do-able in particular when $C=0$. So, you are essentially saying that any generic $E$ can be stabilised, which I think is not very convincing.

Comment: I guess for the particular case of $C=0$, then we can check separately the theorem's condition for $A$ and $E$